# Is it possible to create an instance of a class within the same class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have a class:

```
class Foo{
public:

    Foo(){
    }

    //Is it possible to create a function like this:
    virtual Foo* createOb(){
       //Should create a new Foo,Bar or Fiz, depending on the actual object type.
    }
}

class Bar: public Foo{
public:

    Bar(){
    }
}

class Fiz: public Foo{
public:

    Fiz(){
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have a method `createOb()` in the base class, so when createOb() is called on an instance of one of the derived classes, that an instance of the derived class is created ?

Comment: If you split it up in different cpp files I guess it should be possible. Are you looking for a clone function of the base class without knowing what child class it is? You can take a look at this approach: https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/

Comment: @c.bear But Foo doesn't know about the derived classes...I'm new to C++ so I don't know what you mean...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Bu first, returning a raw pointer obtained from `new` is **very dangerous**. In `c++` raw pointers should be used only when they do not have ownership of the pointed object. So I took the liberty to use `unique_ptr`:

```
struct Base {
  virtual auto create_obj() -> std::unique_ptr<Base>
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>{};
  }
};

// abstract works too:
struct Base {
  virtual auto create_obj() -> std::unique_ptr<Base> = 0;
};

template <class Derived>
struct Base_crtp : Base {
  auto create_obj() -> std::unique_ptr<Base> override /* final */
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new Derived{}};
  }
};

struct D1 : Base_crtp<D1>
{
};

struct D2 : Base_crtp<D2>
{
};
```

And then:

```
auto b1 = std::unique_ptr<Base>{new D1{}};
auto b2 = std::unique_ptr<Base>{new D2{}};

auto new_d1 = b1->create_obj();
auto new_d2 = b2->create_obj();
```

Comment: something which may not everyone will get is how to adopt it to copy constructors (casting the `this` ptr to `Derrived` in `create_obj`. Not sure if it might help to add here in case others use this solution to also copy objects. So this would be `return std::unique_ptr<Base>{new Derived{static_cast<const Derrived&>(*this)}};` if needed.

Comment: @Hayt `clone` is exemplified in the wiki page I linked

Comment: Ah ok. Did not see that was a link there :)

Comment: @Hayt I added it later

Answer (score 1):

Definitely YES!!!

When a method is declared virtual in base class, and called through the derived class object, then the derived class function gets called (Read vprt, vtable concept in c++).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
        public:
        virtual A* getobj(){
        return new A();
        }
};
class B: public A{
        public:
        B(){cout<<"B constructor"<<endl;}
        virtual A* getobj(){
        return new B();
        }
};

int main()
{

A *a = new B();
A *second = a->getobj();
return 0;
}
```

In the above code, we are calling the getobj() function using class B's object.
Here the constructor of class B is called twice.

1. first, for new B() in main
2. secondly for getobj function call which again creates object of B

Comment: I think the ideea was to not write the same code in each derived class. To have the code for `getobj` just in the Base class

Comment: Both function should be in both class

Comment: The problem here is John has a lot of classes. So you need to add this too 100+ classes. Which is what he wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with "pure" inheritance. The classes must override `createOb()` member function in order to support cloning.

You can see why this is not possible by considering separate compilation of classes. An implementation of one-fits-all `createOb()` member function must be completed in isolation from `Bar` and `Fiz`, making it impossible for the base to know the type of its subclasses.

An implementation with a pure virtual function in the base is very common, though.

Another approach is to use *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)* to implement cloning. This [article](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) explains how it can be done.

Comment: Depending on the situation a CRTP based approach is also common. But seeing that John is new to c++ this may get confusing for a beginner.

Comment: @Hayt I'm using something like CRTP already, but its extremely difficult for me to wrap my head around. I would prefer something simpler, even if it is a hack, as long as it just works..

Comment: Sounds like I will have to update all my derived classes! :( Too many...

Comment: Well CRTP is the way without least code duplication. But it can be messy if you are not used to it. Maybe have a look at the blog post I mentioned in the comment and hopefully it clears a bit up.

Comment: CRTP is like the only approach where you only write this "once" and the compiler generates all for you.

Comment: @Hayt I couldn't figure out CRTP in a similar problem I had earlier, so ended up using macros =P

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution, but it works.

In your .h

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
    virtual Foo* createOb();
};

class Bar: public Foo{
public:
    Bar();
};

class Fiz: public Foo{
public:
    Fiz();
};
```

In your .cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

Foo::Foo() {}

Foo* Foo::createOb(){
    if (dynamic_cast<Bar*>(this)) {
        return new Bar();
    }
    else if (dynamic_cast<Foo*>(this)) {
        return new Foo();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

Bar::Bar() {}
Fiz::Fiz() {}
```

As already suggested please consider a pure virtual method

Comment: Seems like John has "a lot" derrived classes though

Comment: The problem is that Foo will have to know about the existence of Bar, Fiz etc... I'm going to try hacking a macro together... XD

Comment: Haye is correct.... I have many derived classes, and will keep adding more!

Comment: @John split code into .h and .cpp and Foo will know everything about Bar and Fiz :)

Comment: @Hayt Sure, this is far from optimal and I would avoid this pattern, but could be a solution if he really doesn't want a pure virtual method.

Comment: Yeah it could be one. Other options would be trying to write a marco for this (as he already mentions try to do) or implement a CRTP way which can get pretty complicated for a c++ beginner. But without code generation the approaches are far from optimal.